# dataimport handler is indexing 0 documents

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, solr4

Hello I'm tring to create dataimport from url

I have url http://domain.loc/path
under this url I have dynamicly generated xml

now I have dataimport like this

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="HttpDataSource" />
    <document>
            <entity name="pages"
                    pk="uid"
                    url="http://domain.loc/?no_cache=1&amp;type=9999"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                    forEach="/items"
                    transformer="DateFormatTransformer">

        <field column="uid" xpath="/items/item/uid" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field column="name" xpath="/items/item/title" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

The xml under this url looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<items>

    <item>
        <uid>1</uid>
        <title>page 1</title>
    </item>

    <item>
        <uid>2</uid>
        <title>page 2.</title>
    </item>
 </items>
```

Dataimport works but it is indexing 0 documents and I don't know why

Comment: you can the DIH in the Debug mode which will help you get the internals of the request and the data Solr gets. Just check if the debug button is available for Solr 4.